# linear-gradient background from center / middle

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

Is there a way to use linear-gradient background which is starting from the center / middle of the screen?

This is my current css:

```
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 800px;
    background: blue;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, black, blue, blue, black 800px);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, black, blue, blue, black 800px);
}
```

Gradient bg is stopping after 800px (what I want), but it is on the right side of the screen, instead of behind the content of the webpage. I cannot move it to anywhere else. Also it is appearing at different distances from the content, depending of the window size. I need it to be fixed to the center, behind my content.

Maybe something like the next line exists?

```
background: linear-gradient(to sides, blue, black 400px);
```

So I'd need to be able to set the starting position of the linear-gradient to the center and let the browser run it to both sides.
400px from center is where it should stop (and after that use the last color) - so a total of 800px wide the gradient should be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If i understand your request correctly, this is what you want:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, blue 400px, black 800px);
  background-size: 800px 100%;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution so far. I'll need to change some other things too, some small problems appeared, like the bottom part of the page got lost. :D

Comment: I tried with margin:0 before too. I wrote it wrong as actually the background was not appearing after the original 100% of the screen height. Needed to change your last line: `background-repeat: repeat-y;` , now it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, black, blue 25%, blue 75%, black 100%);
```

Using percentages ensures your page will scale, and you'll have the left and right quarters of your screen black with the middle half solid blue!

Comment: Thanks, but this way when the browser window is smaller, all the background I see is black. When I check it big monitor fullscreen, the bg around the content is light blue. I need the same colors behind / near the content all time.

Comment: Got it, I didn't read carefully enough to see your content was a fixed-width. In that case, @vals solution should work great